# How do I transfer units to another player?

Tags: freeciv

I usually give financial aid to my frenemies using diplomacy, so that they can continue to harass my enemies. However, sometimes I wish to transfer advanced military units rather than gold. Is there a way to do this?

1. I don't want to give them the technology directly, because I only support them as long as they continue to harass my enemies.
2. I am not allied with my frenemies, so I cannot use my own units to protect their cities.